# How to install gdal using conda in Windows 10 with python 3.7? After I installed geoviews I´ve never managed to use gdal again

Tags: python, conda, gdal

I had to install the geoviews package, which install geopandas and downgraded my gdal version in a way I lost the driver for jp2 files (ECWJPEG2000). I tryed to re-install and I´ve never managed to use again. I use conda for installing and nothing happens. I get a message on the shell saying that the instalation was done, but nothing happens. I can´t import gdal at all. If I use pip for installing, I have a huge error message in red saying that there´s something with the visual studio cl.exe. But the file is there, and visual studio is already whithin my enviromnetal variables. I already reinstall OSGEO4W but it didn´t work.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can try to install gdal from the wheels file [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal). [Here](https://geoffboeing.com/2014/09/using-geopandas-windows/) is another website that walks you through installing all of the other dependencies for geopandas. You will see that for gdal, you will also have to modify your windows path variable to be able to use it from the command line. This could be a reason that your gdal installation is not complete.